# Facebook name ordering and displaying correctly based on country

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I looking at splitting the name supplied by the Facebook API across two lines and I want this to display correctly depending of the country of origin of the person. So the western standard of

```
Given Name
Family Name
```

Where applicable, and

```
Family Name
Given Name
```

in countries where the [names should be reversed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surname#Order_of_names)

Facebook supply a number of name fields

1. **name** - The person's full name
2. **name_format** - The person's name formatted to correctly handle Chinese, Japanese, Korean ordering.
3. **first_name** - The person's first name
4. **last_name** - The person's last name.

I assume **name** is always [Given Name] [Family Name] (may also include middle name?)

**name_format** sounds like it'll be the name in the correct display order

I'm not sure if **first_name** and **last_name** is the indicator of display order, or is **first_name** = [given name] and **last_name** = [family name] as would be assumed in the US?

The real question is how can I split the Facebook display name into given name and family name and then ensure I'm displaying them in the correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, it turns out the **name_format** does not return what the API documentation says, which is:

> The person's name formatted to correctly handle Chinese, Japanese,
>   Korean ordering.

As detailed in the API, but something more akin to what the name would suggest, which is the formatting for the name. In my instance, the return from the API call is as follows.

```
  "name": "Will Calderwood", 
  "name_format": "{first} {last}"
```

I think it's safe to assume that for a Korean locale it would be

```
  "name": "Calderwood Will", 
  "name_format": "{last} {first}"
```

So the **name_format** can be used to break up the name and display it in the correct order.

Comment: Above quote is from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Answer (score 1):

Just tried getting `name_format` back on a user with Chinese/Korean ordering (used typical English name for ease of reading):

Using [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dfirst_name%2C%20last_name%2C%20name%2C%20name_format&version=v2.11) get a token (clicking Get Token button) and requesting the following fields:

```
me?fields=first_name, last_name, name, name_format
```

Returns

> "first_name" = "John"
>
> "last_name" = "Smith"
>
> "name" = "Smith John"
>
> "name_format" = "{first} {last}"

In this case you'd expect it to return `"{last} {first}"`
so looks like `name_format` is completely useless. I've tested it on two users, one with western name order and one like the above, both returned the same name_format value.

Comment: FB lets users choose to reverse the order of their first name and last name. The API doesn't account for this, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

The field `first_name` is the given name, the `last_name` is what you call "family name". To me it's not really clear where your problem is here to be honest.

Comment: I'd like to work out the display order based on country, although I think I've just figured it out. Answer coming shortly.